# Login with formAuthentication in Asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to login or authenticate using FormAuthenticate method in ASP.NET web forms and after login how to check on each page whether user is authenticaed or not.

please give me a sample for that how to use form authentication in login page.

Comment: @Blachshma What framework are you using MVC3? MVC4 classic ASP webforms

Comment: m using the ASP.net web forms.

Comment: Have you looked through MSDN documentation? Is there anything specific that you do not understand there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [FormsAuthentication Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) - validate user

```
public void Login_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text))
   {
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameTextbox.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
   }
   else
     Msg.Text = "Login failed. Please check your user name and password and try again.";
}
```

2) [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

3) Check if user is logged

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //user is logged in
}
else
{
    //user is not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> The page displays the user's authenticated identity, which was set by the FormsAuthentication class and is available in an ASP.NET page as the **`Context.User.Identity.Name`** property.